# Como eliminar las palabras repetidas dentro de una matriz en java?

Tags: java

Necesito un método para eliminar las repeticiones que tiene una palabra dentro de una matriz.

Hasta ahora solo he logrado que lo haga con un vector pero necesito hacer que funciones para una matriz (vector bidimensional).
adjunto mi código.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args){
    String arraycar[][]= new String [2][2];

    arraycar = leerVector("Ingrese el elemento", arraycar.length, arraycar[0].length);


    for(int i=0;i<arraycar.length;i++){

        for(int j=0;j<arraycar[0].length-1;j++){

            if(i!=j){

                if(arraycar[i].equals(arraycar[j])){
                    arraycar[i][j]=" ";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int n=arraycar.length;

        for (int k=0;k<=n;k++){
            for (int m=0;m<=n-1;m++){
                if(arraycar[k][m]!=""){
                    System.out.println( arraycar[k][m]);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Lo que deberías hacer es pedir dos datos: 1) La palabra repetida a buscar en el array, 2) El array donde vas a buscar la palabra ingresada previamente. Así podrías comparar cada palabra que hay en el array con la palabra ingresada (eso se puede hacer con un método booleano) para que así, si el método retorna true eliminas la palabra creando un nuevo array auxiliar sin la palabra repetida.

Comment: Hola @May395, considero tu comentario practicamente como una respuesta sin desarrollar. Yo creo que deberías de eliminar tu comentario y ponerlo como respuesta desarrollando un poco más el mismo e introduciendo el código. Así la pregunta tendría respuesta, nodier solano tendría una explicación más detallada de sus errores y de la forma correcta de programarlo, y tú pordrías lograr más reputación. Un saludo